# Как добавить textField в tableViewCell?

Tags: swift, swift3

Смотрел статьи в интернете и все старые. Знаю, что можно использовать файл tableViewCell и потом в VC файле вызывать эту функцию. Но что-то когда пробую написать код, то появляются ошибки. **Вот мой код с tableViewCell**

```
public class InputScoreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override public func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@IBOutlet weak var inputScore: UITextField!

public func configure(text: String?, placeholder: String) {
    inputScore.text = text
    inputScore.placeholder = placeholder

    inputScore.accessibilityValue = text
    inputScore.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
}
}
```

**Вот мой код с VC**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell() as! InputScoreTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = usersIn[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(text: "0", placeholder: "Score")
    return cell
}
```

И вот ошибка

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1048d9858) to 'Uno_test.InputScoreTableViewCell' (0x10236c7d0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы создаете новый объект класса `UITableViewCell`. Это не Ваш `InputScoreTableViewCell`, он ничего не знает об `inputScore`.

Судя по коду `InputScoreTableViewCell` у Вас ячейка в `Storyboard`. Тогда задайте ей идентификатор и в `cellForRowAt` переиспользуйте ее:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellStoryboardIdentifier") as! InputScoreTableViewCell
```